# JavaScript Regex pull out only a number in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How would one go about pulling out just a number in the text of an element?  I want to set this as a variable.

**ie. If I wanted to have a variable made from option val 171 of the number 12 so I can do calculations with it (I just want to be left with the number 12):**

```
<select id="coloroption">
 <option value="172">Granite Gray</option>
 <option value="174">Hot Red</option>
 <option value="173">Navy</option>
 <option value="171">Kentucky Green (min. 12)</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var number = $('#coloroption option[value="171"]').text().match(/\d+/);
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W9tgH/). Depending on the possible values of this option and what you need to extract from it, the regex might need tweaking.

Comment: I would put the whole thing in parseInt() just to cast it to INT as match returns a string.

Comment: Ok this works as intended.  I also tried wrapping it in parseInt as I have calculations to do using jQuery, however it returns NaN for my calculations now.

Comment: @ToddN What is your string value before executing parseInt?

Answer (score 1):

Darin Dimitrov is the exact answer to your question. +1

However, I'm going to suggest a different approach all together, if you have control over your markup. And that's to use `data-` attributes to explicitly store the information that you want to use, rather than trying to use possibly fragile string parsing to get the data.

```
<option value="171" data-processing-minutes="12">Kentucky Green (min. 12)</option>
```

And then retrieve that attribute with

```
var value = $('#coloroption option[value="171"]').data("processing-minutes");
```

or

```
var value = $('#coloroption option[value="171"]').attr("data-processing-minutes");
```

Though the former is preferred.